# How to replace characters in passwords with * in C

Tags: c, windows, passwords, codeblocks

I've started a few days ago to learn C and created a little console application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
char name[100];
char password[100];

printf("Welcome to Skynet servers, please enter your username and password in the form below. \n");
printf("username: ");
scanf(" %s", name);
printf("password: ");
scanf(" %s", password);

if(strcmp(password, "skynet") == 0){
    printf("\n Welcome, Mr. %s, to your personal Skynet account", name);
}else {
    printf("ERROR: USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT. LEAVE THIS TERMINAL OR SECURITY WILL BE ALERTED!!!");
}


return 0;
}
```

I want the password to be masked with * while writing it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into `getch()`. It works like `getchar()` but doesn't echo the character. The idea here is to use `getch()` in a loop until the newline character (`\n`) is inputted. Print a `*` on each input of a  character. You might also need to check for the backspace character (`\b`).

Comment: In fairness to the OP, this is not obvious for a console app.